# Why does internal energy decrease when work is done by system

Tags: thermodynamics

According to the physics book ,if work is done by system internal energy will decrease but heat is also added so why interal energy is deceased?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If more heat is added than the work done by the system, then the internal energy will indeed increase. But if less is added than the work done, the internal energy will decrease. This follows from a special case of energy conservation, the First Law of Thermodynamics, which may be written
$$\Delta U=Q-W$$
in which $\Delta U$ is the increase in internal energy of a system when heat $Q$ enters the system and $W$ is the work done by the system.